# Nested Collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

```
const onboarderSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "name field is required"]
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  project: {
    type: Object,
    projectName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true]
    },
    projectDescription: {
      type: String
    },
    manager: {
      type: String,
      required: [true]
    },
    mentor: {
      type: String,
      required: [true]
    },
    technologies: {
      type: [Number],
      required: [true]
    }
  }
});
```

This is a schema for my project which I am working on. The Project which is an object will have different projects added to it dynamically. So should I change the type of project to an array or something else? Cannot figure out what to do. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it array. Remember object is for a single information with fixed fields and values. on the other hand, array is to hold many information where you can put objects as many as you need dynamically. Then it will be called an array of objects. Keep the object fields same in the array to keep consistency and flexible query operation.

Comment: I converted it into an array of objects. And it seems to work fine. But what should I do when I have to update any field of a specific in the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple project inside your database the project field should be an array like

```
project:[{projectName:"p1"},
         {projectName:"p2"},
         {projectName:"p3"}]
```

or like this

```
project:["p1","p2","p3"]
```

Comment: I converted it into an array of objects. And it seems to work fine. But what should I do when I have to update any field of a specific in the array?

Comment: db.table.update({"project.projectName":"p2"},{$set:{"project.$.projectName":"p4"}})